# Print embedded PDF with Javascript fails

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I am working on a project that I need to be multi-browser compatible and I am having a problem causing the Adobe Reader Print Dialog to be activated and displayed in all other browsers except IE.  I embed the PDF in the broswer using the object tag like this:

```
<object id="pdfObj" type="application/pdf" style="width:60%;height:95%;position:relative;top:2%;left:0%;right:10%;bottom:10%;margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px;" data="PDFView.aspx"></object>
```

I use jQuery to catch the click of the print link as such:

```
                $('#PrintLink').click(function () {
                $("#pdfObj")[0].print();
            });
```

This works with IE, but when run in Firefox with the Web Developer tools running the error "$("#pdfObj")[0].print is not a function" is caught.  With Chrome I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object# has no method print.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished with these other browsers?  You answers will be greatly appreciated.

James

Comment: We have successfully embedded a javascript in the pdf itself to activate the print dialog

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I have been searching for a solution to this for the past week. The problem is that Firefox will not let you access the element if the URL of the page does not start with www. Try adding this script to the top of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( location.host.toLowerCase().substring(0,3) != "www" )
    {
        location.href = location.href.replace( /\/\//, "//www." );
    }
</script>
```

This will redirect the user to a the same URL but adds www. to the start of it.

Then embed your pdf in an iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="myPDF.pdf" width="200" height="500"></iframe>
```

Then you can use this javascript function to print the PDF:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.print();
```

You can perform a check in JavaScript to see what browser the user has if you need different code for IE and Safari.
Hope this helps, it worked for me.